# React Native Posting/Fetching to Backend

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-emulator, fetch-api

I am having trouble posting data to an express backend with React Native via Android Emulator. The goal of the app is to allow customers to post microtask requests like home chores and lawn care where all the data will be stored to a AWS RDS MySQL Server. On the flip side there are freelancers who can view the customer posts through a feed. (For more background view here: https://askfavr.com) Now that you know the background onto the issue.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,
    TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView,
    TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage, ScrollView
} from "react-native";


export default class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        request: {
            C_Name: '', //this is a placeholder for the addRequest()  method
            Email: '',
            Phone: '',
            Category: '',
            Time_Length: '',
            Street: '',
            City: '',
            C_State: '',
            Zip: '',
            Finish_Before: '',
            Price: '',
            Details: ''
        }
    }

    /* Just like getRequests, addRequest does exactly what its named as well. It adds a request
      to the MySQL database following the initialization of the request state. The addRequest()
      uses the post method which then returns are query string containing the new data submitted */
    addRequest = _ => {
        const { request } = this.state;
        //query string set to remote server  
        fetch(`http://192.168.56.1:4000/requests/add?C_Name=${request.C_Name}&Email=${request.Email}&Phone=${request.Phone}&Category=${request.Category}&Time_Length=${request.Time_Length}&Street=${request.Street}&City=${request.City}&C_State=${request.C_State}&Zip=${request.Zip}&Finish_Before=${request.Finish_Before}&Price=${request.Price}&Details=${request.Details}`)
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }

    render() {
        const { request } = this.state; //set state for addRequest()
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.wrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.header}> Yardwork Request </Text>
                <ScrollView>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Name:' value={request.C_Name}
                        onChangeText={Name => this.setState(request.C_Name)}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Email:' value={request.Email}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Email: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Phone:' value={request.Phone}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Phone: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Category:' value={request.Category}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Category: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Time of Job:' value={request.Time_Length}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Time_Length: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Street:' value={request.Street}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Street: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='City:' value={request.City}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, City: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='State:' value={request.C_State}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, C_State: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Zip:' value={request.Zip}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Zip: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Complete By:' value={request.Finish_Before}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Finish_Before: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Price:' value={request.Price}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Price: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Details:' value={request.Details}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Details: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.btn}
                        onPress={this.addRequest}>
                        <Text> Request </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </ScrollView>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        paddingLeft: 40,
        paddingRight: 40,
    },
    header: {
        fontSize: 24,
        marginTop: 25,
        color: '#000000',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    TextInput: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        padding: 16,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderRadius: 12,
        color: '#000000',
        fontSize: 16,
        //backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    btn: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        padding: 20,
        borderRadius: 12,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    small: {
        fontSize: 15,
        color: '#000000',
        paddingTop: 10,
    },
});
```

when I try to run essentially the same thing in react native I get this error

**setState(...) takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables**

but in Plain React I can use nearly the exact code with no problem and post data easily

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        requests: [], //null state for the getRequests() method
        request: {
            C_Name: '', //this is a placeholder for the addRequest()  method
            Email: '',
            Phone: '' ,
            Category: '',
            Time_Length:'' ,
            Street:'' ,
            City:'' , 
            C_State:'' ,
            Zip:'' , 
            Finish_Before:'' ,
            Price: '',
            Details: ''
        }
    }

    /* Mounts the "getRequests" to display on the screen, instead of writing the 
  full method within the componentDidMount() 
  componentDidMount() Purpose: this method takes place before rendering to
  essentially change the state of the arrays and variables if they are no
  longer null. */
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getRequests();
    }

    getRequests = _ => {
        fetch('http://192.168.56.1:4000/requests')
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then(response => this.setState({ requests: response.data}))
        .catch( err => console.error(err))
    }

    /* Just like getRequests, addRequest does exactly what its named as well. It adds a request
    to the MySQL database following the initialization of the request state. The addRequest()
    uses the post method which then returns are query string containing the new data submitted */
    addRequest =_ => {
        const { request } = this.state;
        //query string set to remote server  
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/requests/add?C_Name=${request.C_Name}&Email=${request.Email}&Phone=${request.Phone}&Category=${request.Category}&Time_Length=${request.Time_Length}&Street=${request.Street}&City=${request.City}&C_State=${request.C_State}&Zip=${request.Zip}&Finish_Before=${request.Finish_Before}&Price=${request.Price}&Details=${request.Details}`) 
        .then(this.getRequests)
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }


    //Fields of Data for a FAVR Request: 
    //idyard_record, time_posted, C_Name, Email, Phone, Category, Time_Length, Street, City, C_State, Zip, Finish_Before, Price
    //Details, RequestID, Proposals
    renderRequest = ({ idyard_record, C_Name, Category }) => 
        <div key={idyard_record}>{C_Name}: <b>{Category} </b><br/><br/> </div> //displays all requests from the MySQL data similar to a flatlist
    render() {
        const { requests, request} = this.state; //set state for getRequests() && getRequest()


        const mainDiv = {
            align: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            flex: '1',
            margin: '2%'
        }
        const divStyle = {
            margin: '2%',
        };

        const inputBorder = {
            borderColor: 'lightgrey',
            padding: '5px',
            marginTop: '1%',
            marginLeft: '1%'
        }

        return (
            <div className="App" style={mainDiv} >
                {requests.map(this.renderRequest)}
                <div>
                    <div style={divStyle} > 
                        <label style={{align: 'left'}} > Name: </label> 
                        <input style={inputBorder} value={request.C_Name} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, C_Name: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div>
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> Email: </label> 
                        <input style={inputBorder} value={request.Email} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, Email: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div> 
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label style={{textAlign: 'left'}} > Phone: </label> 
                        <input style={inputBorder} value={request.Phone} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, Phone: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div> 
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> Category: </label> 
                        <input style={inputBorder} value={request.Category} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, Category: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div> 
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> Time of Job: </label> 
                        <input style={inputBorder} value={request.Time_Length} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, Time_Length: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div> 
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> Street: </label> 
                        <input style={inputBorder} value={request.Street} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, Street: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div>
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> City: </label> 
                        <input style={inputBorder} value={request.City} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, City: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div>  
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> State: </label> 
                        <input style={inputBorder} value={request.C_State} 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, C_State: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div>  
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> Zip: </label> 
                        <input style={inputBorder} value={request.Zip} placeholder='55901' 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, Zip: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div> 
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> Complete By: </label> 
                        <input type="datetime-local" style={inputBorder} value={request.Finish_Before} placeholder='55901' 
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: {...request, Finish_Before: e.target.value}})} /> 
                    </div>
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> Price: </label> 
                        $<input type="number" style={inputBorder} value={request.Price} placeholder='$20'
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Price:  e.target.value }})} />
                    </div> 
                    <div style={divStyle} >
                        <label> Details: </label> 
                        <textarea rows={3} style={inputBorder} value={request.Details}
                        onChange={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Details:  e.target.value }})} />
                    </div> 
                    <button onClick={this.addRequest}> Request FAVR </button> 
                </div> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Does anyone have suggestions to resolve this issue? I know the backend isn't  the issue because the plain react app can post to it, and the emulator/plain react app can display the data from the MySQL DB with no issue.

[image of react native error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34bkH.jpg)

Comment: which part of script getting this error?Could you please highlight it

Comment: I believe whenever I use the setState() function the error typically logs. I did attach an image at the bottom as well which gave me the emulator screen of death. Here is one of the example scripts that returns an error:   <TextInput
                        style={styles.TextInput} placeholder='Email:' value={request.Email}
                        onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Email: e.target.value } })}
                        underlineColorAndroid='black'
                    />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic one seems to be this one:

```
    onChangeText={Name => this.setState(request.C_Name)}
```

This line is in the React Native code, but not the plain React code, so that's the difference between the two. You should be passing `setState()` an object, something like:

```
    this.setState({ request: {...request, C_Name: e.target.value}})
```

similar to what you do for the other ones.

Comment: Yes so I changed the name and now I'm getting an error: "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'e.target.value')

Comment: Well my example was just assuming you passed `e` as a parameter in the arrow function. In your code you pass `Name` as the parameter, so you may have to set the `C_Name` property based on that, e.g. `onChangeText={Name => this.setState({ request: {...request, C_Name: Name}})}`. I can't tell the specifics of how the fix would look, but you get the idea

Comment: Yeah this worked to help me get to the write answer. I actually posted an answer myself and realized that I have three issues with the code above  and this was one of the issues, so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue changing three things:

1. **In React Native you can't have state alone, you have to configure the changing state items to be passed through a constructor**

*so instead of this: *

```
state = {
    request: {
        C_Name: '', //this is a placeholder for the addRequest()  method
        Email: '',
        Phone: '',
        Category: '',
        Time_Length: '',
        Street: '',
        City: '',
        C_State: '',
        Zip: '',
        Finish_Before: '',
        Price: '',
        Details: ''
    }
}
```

**you have to change the state variables to this**

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  request: {
    C_Name: '', //this is a placeholder for the addRequest()  method
    Email: '',
    Phone: '',
    Category: '',
    Time_Length: '',
    Street: '',
    City: '',
    C_State: '',
    Zip: '',
    Finish_Before: '',
    Price: '',
    Details: ''
  }
}
```

2. **Second, when you use a submit button I advise to use parentheses for the submit function**

*instead of this*

```
addRequest = _ => {
    const { request } = this.state;
    //query string set to remote server  
    fetch(`http://192.168.56.1:4000/requests/add?C_Name=${request.C_Name}&Email=${request.Email}&Phone=${request.Phone}&Category=${request.Category}&Time_Length=${request.Time_Length}&Street=${request.Street}&City=${request.City}&C_State=${request.C_State}&Zip=${request.Zip}&Finish_Before=${request.Finish_Before}&Price=${request.Price}&Details=${request.Details}`)
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

**you have to change the function to this:**

```
addRequest = () => {
const { request } = this.state;
//query string set to remote server  
fetch(`http://192.168.56.1:4000/requests/add?C_Name=${request.C_Name}&Email=${request.Email}&Phone=${request.Phone}&Category=${request.Category}&Time_Length=${request.Time_Length}&Street=${request.Street}&City=${request.City}&C_State=${request.C_State}&Zip=${request.Zip}&Finish_Before=${request.Finish_Before}&Price=${request.Price}&Details=${request.Details}`)
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
}
```

3. **Lastly, you have to properly pass the onchange text. You can't use target value like you would in plain react.**

*So instead of using this*

```
onChangeText={e => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Email: e.target.value } })}
```

**disregard `e.target.value` and just change it to something like this (use a different variable for each input of course)**

```
onChangeText={(Email) => this.setState({ request: { ...request, Email: Email } })}
```

So in summary, make sure the state is passed under a constructor, second use `() =>` for the submit function instead of `_ =>` and finally make sure that you properly pass the input object. **Remember**, `.target.value` doesn't work with React Native like it does with plain react.